# Should each method have its own object created everytime

Tags: java, design, coding-standards

I have a bit of confusion whether a method should create an instance of a class each time it's invoked? It is all possible to move this instance creation part to the constructor and just use the reference to call methods, but what is the best way ??

***Code >>***

```
Class B{
   void readFromS3(){// this method reads from a S3 bucket}
   void writeToS3(){// this method writes to a S3 bucket}
}
```

**Approach A**

```
public class A{
 private B b;
 public A(){
   this.b = new B();
 }

 void someMethodInA(){
      b.readFromS3();
      b.writeToS3();
 }
}
```

**Approach B**

```
public class A{
 public A(){
   // nothing here
 }

 void someMethodInA(){
      B b = new B();
      b.readFromS3();
      b.writeToS3();
 }
```

In what cases should each approach be used? 
Thanks.. !!

Comment: Con you provide a bit more context? It's hard to tell without knowing what's the particular purpose of `A` and `B`.

Comment: Both cases have two different meanings. You cannot compare them as they are not interexchangeable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ updated

Comment: @Euphoric updated the code..

Comment: Still different meanings.

Comment: The constructor **is** what *creates* the instance.  Your question doesn't therefore make sense.

Comment: The issue at hand is that there are at least two viable places where an instance of B class can be created inside class A.. One is the constructor and another one is inside each method for each time it is called

Comment: Honestly, this is a question which cannot be answered in a sensible manner by using terms like `A` and `B` as class names. Give your classes and objects proper names and responsibilities, maybe some documentation, then it becomes obvious what their correct life time must be. In the current form, I see the question based on the very wrong assumption that names like "A" and "B" are sufficient for an answer.

Comment: *If it doesn't matter* then why aren't `readFromS3` and `writeToS3` static?

Comment: The general answer would be  `public A(B b){this.b = b;}` unless you have a specific reason why B lifecycle should be tied to A's one.

Answer (score 7):

Objects have meaning. Their existence should be dependent on that meaning, not just on some abstract "I need to call some methods" idea. In other words, the lifetime of your objects should be obvious from their purpose.

If your objects don't have meaning, that just means you misdesigned your objects.

Comment: I strongly agree with your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly - it is a matter of design. And of course, the design should take care of memory utilization etc.

There might be cases that approach A can fit better than B (which is completely different, and again - a matter of design or even requirements), and vice versa...

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, it depends. Possible considerations could be:

- How much resources does a B instance consume? In terms of memory use or claims on scarce operating system objects that are supposed to be released as soon as possible. How expensive is it to instantiate B?
- How often is the B-method called?
- What do you care about execution speed of the B-method, is that an issue at all?
- When B is created,does its state represent a snapshot of something that will soon go stale or is an old B just as good as a new one?

This all makes the decision lean towards one or the other way.

Comment: This answer kind of ignores the purpose of the objects. If the object is say a button for an UI screen, then you should create as many buttons as you actually need for the UI... you don't decide to create more button than needed because execution speed is low or vice versa.

Comment: @JacquesB  So that is just another dependency one could add to the list. "Do the objects need to be alive simultaneously or not?"

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of design. More precisely, the design of class A. Class A represents an abstraction of some entity. That abstraction has some state. If class B is a part of that state, then B should be a member of that class. If it is not, then it should not be a member of that class.

This latter case, though, does not mean that you should instantiate class B in a method of class A where a method of B should be invoked. It might be sufficient to just pass B as an argument.